# Creating and using a table with a composite primary key in SQLite.Net-PCL

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, orm

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/pull/160) that SQLite.Net-PCL does not support composite PKs, a feature I need in my case if I do not want to fall back to constructs like

```
create table something(value varchar primary key not null);
insert into something(value) values("$Value1,$Value2");
```

Manually (without using ORM) creating a table with a composite primary key also does not work, throwing the same `SQLiteException`, telling me that my table has multiple primary keys.

The table's layout is like this

```
class ChannelBinding {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

and I was wondering if there is any known workaround that would be able to emulate the behaviour of a composite PK.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a composite unique key.

```
class ChannelBinding {
    [Indexed(Name = "CompositeKey", Order = 1, Unique = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Indexed(Name = "CompositeKey", Order = 2, Unique = true)]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can someone comment if this solved the issue for them? Or better still mark as accepted?

Comment: Not solved. Updating such entity fails with NotSupportedException "Cannot update <EntityName>: it has no PK"